# Converting a ctypes.c_void_p() and ctypes.c_size_t() to bytearray or string?

Tags: ctypes

I can't seem to find any simple examples of converting a `ctypes.c_void_p()` to a string or byte array. Is there any simple one liner that will do this?

Answer (score 4):

Here you go:

```py
import ctypes as ct

# set up some void pointers to valid string and byte array
data = b'some string\0with null in it'
data1 = ct.c_char_p(data)
size1 = ct.c_size_t(len(data))
data2 = (ct.c_ubyte * 8)(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
size2 = ct.c_size_t(8)
void1 = ct.cast(data1, ct.c_void_p)  # void* to nul-terminated string
void2 = ct.cast(data2, ct.c_void_p)  # void* to eight bytes of data
print(void1, size1)
print(void2, size2)

# cast void* to the data being pointed to, and retrieve its contents
s = ct.cast(void1, ct.POINTER(ct.c_char * size1.value)).contents
print(s)
print(s.value) # up to nul-termination
print(s.raw)   # full array

# cast void* to the data being pointed to, and retrieve its contents
b = ct.cast(void2, ct.POINTER(ct.c_ubyte * size2.value)).contents
print(b)
print(b[2])
print(list(b))
```

Output:

```
c_void_p(1678408544912) c_ulonglong(27)
c_void_p(1678408467720) c_ulonglong(8)
<__main__.c_char_Array_27 object at 0x00000186C8F0CBC0>
b'some string'
b'some string\x00with null in it'
<__main__.c_ubyte_Array_8 object at 0x00000186C8F0C840>
3
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 2):

I did this

`data = bytearray(ctypes.string_at(data_ptr, data_size.value))`